# jquery simple image changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

Hello everyone I have this code to change multiple images like slideshow

```
function test() {
   $(".topimg img").first().appendTo('.topimg').fadeOut(1000);
   $(".topimg img").first().fadeIn(1000);
   setTimeout(test, 7000);
}
test();
```

But I have one problem when I minimize browser or change tab and when I back image are changing too fast.How can I fix that and please fix this code do not give me another one with javascript or anything this is the simple one.

Comment: Still I doesn't figure how to fix this it's like browser try to compensate image that are show in time when I don't look in website I forgot to mention that jquery function is .ready

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
 function test() {
       $(".topimg img").first().appendTo('.topimg').fadeOut(1000);
       $(".topimg img").first().fadeIn(1000);
 }

 setTimeout(function(){test();}, 7000);
```

Comment: in this case my script stop work when I change tab and go back to the page

Answer (score 0):

The rendering is paused while tab is not in view. It would be appropriate to pause the logic as well, so the browser does not need to catch up with the events when the page comes into view again.

- Chrome page visibility API: https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility
- Firefox's: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

I'm sure there are ways to detect this in other browsers, but I've never used those, so no reference comes to mind for those.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.
`setInterval` will call test after each 7000 milli seconds. if you want run test immediately you can call it just after setInteval;

I added inteval variable to check if setInterval is already running if so don't call setInterval.

```
   if(window.inteval){
      return
   }
    function test() {
       $(".topimg img").first().appendTo('.topimg').fadeOut(1000);
       $(".topimg img").first().fadeIn(1000);
    }
    if(!window.inteval){
         window.inteval = setInterval(test, 7000);
   }
```

Same way you can put check on your code

```
   function test() {
       $(".topimg img").first().appendTo('.topimg').fadeOut(1000);
       $(".topimg img").first().fadeIn(1000);
       window.interval = setTimeout(test, 7000);
    }
   if( !window.interval){
       test();
   }
```